# Cannot find library installed with vcpkg

Tags: c++, cmake, vcpkg

I have install `spdlog` with `vcpkg` corretly, but unfortunately my `CMakeLists.txt` still not find it.

```
CMake Error at C:/src/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:853 (_find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "spdlog" with any
  of the following names:

    spdlogConfig.cmake
    spdlog-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "spdlog" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "spdlog_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "spdlog"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:38 (find_package)
```

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.15 FATAL_ERROR )
message(STATUS "Using toolchain file: ${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE}")

project( test VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX )
find_package(spdlog CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

I have  included `find_package(spdlog CONFIG REQUIRED)` in the `CmakeLists.txt`. The library is installed correctly.

```
spdlog:x64-windows                                1.11.0#1            Very fast, header only, C++ logging library
```

[image]

I have been digging the internet but I still don't know why it cannot find `spdlogConfig.cmake`. Any suggestions to start to debug this?

**Edit:** The project is configured for Visual Studio.

Comment: Do you configure your project for Visual Studio or for MinGW?

Comment: "I have install spdlog with vcpkg corretly" - But you cannot use it, so why are you so sure you installed it correctly?

Comment: Try setting the cmake variable `VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET` to `x64-windows`